# Why is Numpy's random.normal so fast?

Tags: python, c++, c, numpy

I am trying to run Monte Carlo simulations which require the generation of a large number of pairs (e.g. 10,000) of normally distributed and correlated random variables at each time step. I would like to take advantage of vectorization by drawing a vector of 10,000 random normal variables at each time step and apply some transformation to it.

I first tried C++. I implemented it with `std::valarray` and found out the time taken was not very ideal.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <valarray>
#include <chrono>  

using namespace std;
using std::chrono::duration;
using std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;

int main()
{
    int num_sim = 100000;
    double rho = -0.7;

    auto t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();

    for(int i = 0; i<1000; ++i) {
        random_device rd;
        mt19937 gen(rd());
        normal_distribution<> distr(0,1);

        auto generator = [&distr, &gen]() {return distr(gen);};

        valarray<double> norm1(num_sim);
        valarray<double> norm2(num_sim);
        generate(begin(norm1), end(norm1), generator);
        generate(begin(norm2), end(norm2), generator);

        norm2 = rho*norm1 + sqrt((1-rho*rho))*norm2;
    }

    auto t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();

    duration<double> elapsed = t2 - t1;

    cout<<"\nTime taken: "<<elapsed.count()<<"s\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The time taken was 20.6613s on my machine using a g++ compiler.

Next, I tried it with NumPy.

```python
import time
import numpy as np

num_sim = 100000
rho = -0.7

t1 = time.time()

for i in range(1000):
    norm1 = np.random.normal(0, 1, num_sim)
    norm2 = np.random.normal(0, 1, num_sim)
    norm2 = rho*norm1 + np.sqrt((1-rho*rho))*norm2;

t2 = time.time()

print(f"Time taken: {t2-t1} seconds")
```

The time taken was 5.0129s on my machine. While I decided to go with NumPy for the simulations and I understand there is a substantial difference between those two languages, I would still like to know the reasons for this.

The following is part of the source code in C for the normal distribution in NumPy.

```c
double random_standard_normal(bitgen_t *bitgen_state) {
  uint64_t r;
  int sign;
  uint64_t rabs;
  int idx;
  double x, xx, yy;
  for (;;) {
    /* r = e3n52sb8 */
    r = next_uint64(bitgen_state);
    idx = r & 0xff;
    r >>= 8;
    sign = r & 0x1;
    rabs = (r >> 1) & 0x000fffffffffffff;
    x = rabs * wi_double[idx];
    if (sign & 0x1)
      x = -x;
    if (rabs < ki_double[idx])
      return x; /* 99.3% of the time return here */
    if (idx == 0) {
      for (;;) {
        /* Switch to 1.0 - U to avoid log(0.0), see GH 13361 */
        xx = -ziggurat_nor_inv_r * npy_log1p(-next_double(bitgen_state));
        yy = -npy_log1p(-next_double(bitgen_state));
        if (yy + yy > xx * xx)
          return ((rabs >> 8) & 0x1) ? -(ziggurat_nor_r + xx)
                                     : ziggurat_nor_r + xx;
      }
    } else {
      if (((fi_double[idx - 1] - fi_double[idx]) * next_double(bitgen_state) +
           fi_double[idx]) < exp(-0.5 * x * x))
        return x;
    }
  }
}
```

As I am not very familiar with C and I just started C++ programming a while ago, I would like to ask:

- How does NumPy achieve this performance?
- What am I doing wrong with C++? Am I not going "low-level" enough?
- How can I achieve the performance on par with or even better than NumPy with C++?

Comment: The first question is always whether you compiled with optimizations turned on

Comment: numpy is already using c++ under the hood and has had numerous expert developers optimizing it over the years. It is unlikely that you'll beat its performance...

Comment: use `steady_clock` rather than `high_resolution_clock`, then turn on optimizations `-O3`

Comment: You can also turn on the `-mavx` and `-mavx2` so to use the more recent SIMD instruction set on x86-64 machines. Numpy uses it when available at runtime, but not C/C++ compiler for sake of retro-compatibility. Note that `-ffast-math` could also speed up the code but it is a bit unsafe if there are NaN values or if you care about the FP associativity. Besides, one can just use a xor instead of `if (sign & 0x1) x = -x;` (though a clever compiler might be able to do that). Branches are slow, especially unpredictable ones.

Comment: If you do turn on `-O3`, be aware that your loop has no observable behaviour, so the compiler is within it's rights to omit it.

Comment: It doesn't help that the C++ code recreates the infrastructure/machinery for generating the random values in every loop iteration.

Comment: Move the random device and the random engine *outside* the loop. Also note that `valarray` is mostly legacy.

Comment: @UnholySheep My apologies for posting this question before considering compiler issues. Lesson learned. The runtime was reduced to about 5.82s when I turn on the optimization flag `-O3` and about 6.72s with `-O` using `g++` from the command line (previously I was using `cmake` with CLion)